# as3 performance

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to experiment with actionscript using flashDevelop and looking at different tutorials online. But when i try to copy and paste code from a tutorial and run it myself the performance it extremely slower. For example i was looking at this tutorial about particles http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/squeezing-more-juice-out-of-the-flash-player/ that shows a warterfall effect at the bottom it runs fine in my browser but if i copy the code and run it in flashDevelop it runs really slow even though its the same code. I have no idea why and cant find anything online. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: did you set your framerate to 30 like they suggested?

Comment: yeah everything is the same. Ive had the same problem before following a tutorial on quickBox2d. copied code from a tuitorial which had examples on the site that ran fine but when compiled in flashDevelop by me it ran slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's the extra overhead of being in debug mode in FlashDevelop? Try opening the `swf` that was compiled in your browser or in Flash Player and see if it still runs slow?

Comment: Opening the swf in the browser made it play properly and not at a slow framerate. I had tried compiling the code as release and not debug so dont understand why, any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I know when I run a swf from FlashDevelop that I can switch back to FlashDevelop while it's running to look at which function the program is in, what variables are in use and values they hold, etc. I haven't tried this in release mode, but I assume it does the same thing. So if it's tracking stuff back and forth between the two programs for thousands of otherwise-small objects, it will suck up processing.

Answer (score 1):

They had mentioned a point in the Speed Test #4.

> CAUTION: The regular createMovieClipCircles() method is so inefficient
>   that you should not let it run for more than a few seconds. The Flash
>   Player will continue to slow down until it eventually grinds to a
>   halt.

Have a look there. :)

Comment: The code thats running slow for me is the same as whats running fast for me in the browser. the warterfall bit at the botom thats just using bitmaps and setPixel.